# How to produce \\ at end of line with kramdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, mathjax, kramdown

I have a Jekyll site hosted on github pages. I have successfully loaded MathJax in my `_layouts/default.html` and now want to author my document. I have tried to set all cofiguration to default to not complicate matters.

The problem is that in some MathJax environments you want to write `\\` to denote a newline (such as the `align` environment, but backslash is a special character in markdown. See example below.

#### Desired output

```html
<p>\begin{align}
x&amp;=3+2\\
 &amp;=5
\end{align}</p>
```

Since one must escape backslash in markdown, I have writte the document below

#### Current input

```markdown
\\begin{align}
x&=3+2\\\\
 &=5
\\end{align}
```

running `kramdown myfile.md` produces

#### Current output

```html
<p>\begin{align}
x&amp;=3+2\<br />
 &amp;=5
\end{align}</p>
```

This is expected given the [kramdown syntax for paragraphs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#paragraphs).

How do I get kramdown to output `\\` at the end of the row, instead of giving me a `\<br />`?

Answer (score 0):

kramdown has some support for MathJax, which i just [found in the documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks). The easy way to do get it right is with input

```markdown
$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=3+2\\
 &=5
\end{aligned}
$$
```

producing

```html
\[\begin{aligned}
x&amp;=3+2\\
 &amp;=5
\end{aligned}\]
```

and that is for all intents and purposes the same as above. There are subtle semantic differences (one equation on two lines vs two equations), but it will look the same. So it is a valid solution to me.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Wrapping the "math" with `$$` tells Kramdown to not parse the content as Markdown.